# Merging sums of numbers from different files and deleting select duplicate lines

Tags: bash, awk, merge

I've checked other threads here on merging, but they seem to be mostly about merging text, and not quite what I needed, or at least I couldn't figure out a way to connect their solutions to my own problem.

#### Problem

I have 10+ input files, each consisting of two columns of numbers (think of them as x,y data points for a graph). Goals:

- Merge these files into 1 file for plotting
- For any duplicate x values in the merge, add their respective y-values together, then print one line with x in field 1 and the added y-values in field 2.

Consider this example for 3 files:

y1.dat

```
 25 16

 27 18
```

y2.dat

```
 24 10

 27 9
```

y3.dat

```
 24 2

 29 3
```

According to my goals above, I should be able to merge them into one file with output:

final.dat

```
 24 12

 25 16

 27 27

 29 3
```

#### Attempt

So far, I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

loops=3

for i in `seq $loops`; do
if [ $i == 1 ]; then
cp -f y$i.dat final.dat

else
awk 'NR==FNR { arr[NR] = $1; p[NR] = $2; next }  {
       for (n in arr) {
       if ($1 == arr[n]) {
       print $1, p[n] + $2
       n++
       }
      }
   print $1, $2 
}' final.dat y$i.dat >> final.dat

fi
done
```

Output:

```
 25 16
 27 18
 24 10
 27 27
 27 9
 24 12
 24 2
 29 3
```

On closer inspection, it's clear I have duplicates of the original x-values.

The problem is my script needs to print all the x-values first, and then I can add them together for my output. However, I don't know how to go back and remove the lines with the old x-values that I needed to make the addition.

If I blindly use uniq, I don't know whether the old x-values or the new x-value is deleted. With awk '!duplicate[$1]++' the order of lines deleted was reversed over the loop, so it deletes on the first loop correctly but the wrong ones after that.

Been at this for a long time, would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you already merged all the files into a single one before making the calculation. Once that's done the script is as simple as  :

```
awk '{ if ( $1 != "" ) { coord[$1]+=$2 } } END { for ( k in coord ) { print k " " coord[k] } }' input.txt
```

Hope it helps!

#### Edit : How this works ?

```
if ( $1 != "" )  { coord[$1]+=$2 }
```

This line will get executed for each line in your input. It will first check whether there is a value for X, otherwise it simply ignores the line. This helps to ignore empty lines should your file have any. The block which gets executed : **coord[$1]+=$2** is the heart of the script and creates a dictionary with X being the key of each entry and at the same time it adds each value for Y found.

```
END { for ( k in coord ) { print k " " coord[k] }
```

This block will execute after awk has iterated over all the lines in your file. It will simply grab each key from the dictionary and print it, then a space and finally the sum of all the values which were found, or in other words, the value for that specific key.

Comment: It seems to work. Thanks a lot. Would you mind explaining how this command "knows" to add duplicates and delete the leftovers?

Comment: I have edited to clarify a little bit. Basically, if you read about hash tables ( or dictionaries or associative arrays) you will clearly see why this works and why there are no duplicates.  Here is a link for that : https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/awk-arrays-explained-with-5-practical-examples/

Comment: In idiomatic awk `{ if ( $1 != "" ) { coord[$1]+=$2 } }` is written `$1 != ""{ coord[$1]+=$2 }` or even just `NF{ coord[$1]+=$2 }`

Comment: @EdMorton awesome tips. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl one-liner

```
> cat y1.dat
25 16
27 18
> cat y2.dat
24 10
27 9
> cat y3.dat
24 2
29 3
> perl -lane ' $kv{$F[0]}+=$F[1]; END { print "$_ $kv{$_}" for(sort keys %kv) }' y*dat
24 12
25 16
27 27
29 3
>
```